# Find elements by multiple class names in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying automate one function on Amazon's site at [this URL](https://www.amazon.in/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.in%2F%3Fref_%3Dnav_custrec_signin&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=inflex&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&).

I am getting an empty list when I am debugging this line:

```java
List<WebElement> e = driver.findElements(By.className("a-box-inner a-padding-extra-large"));
```

The source code of the site appears as follows:

[image]

My question is, why am I getting an empty list and not the list with all of the elements of the `div` that is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one class name can be used with the [`By.className(String)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#className(java.lang.String)) method. From the JavaDoc:

> Find elements based on the value of the "class" attribute. Only one class name should be used. If an element has multiple classes, please use cssSelector(String).

You can use the [`By.cssSelector(String)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#cssSelector(java.lang.String)) method instead:

```java
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='a-box-inner a-padding-extra-large']"));
```

Comment: thanks. do you know why in this way I am getting list with 1 value and not all elements that appears in the image?

Comment: The current setup is giving you the outer element. If you want the inner elements, then I believe you can do `e.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"))` (where `e` is the 1 element you just found). Or you could modify the CSS query to target all of the inner elements (maybe something like `div.a-box-inner.a-padding-extra-large > *` but I haven't tested it).

Comment: `"//div[@class='a-box-inner a-padding-extra-large']/*"` worked for me